# Polymer: Determining when properties have loaded?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I know the `attached` function doesn't guarantee that properties will be loaded.

Right now, I've been using a `computed` Function that depends on properties but it's very clunky.

I've also used `async` but I find it to be inconsistent and arbitrary (just picking a random time to delay by).

I can't find anything about the correct way to deal with this problem.

Comment: Yup that works. Thanks

Comment: `attached` callback guarantees that properties are loaded with its default values set. Not sure what problems you're facing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use observers.

for example you

```
 properties:{
       someproperty:{type:Number,observer:'change'}
 },
 change:function(){
  //this function called when the property changes.
 }
```

for more information look at https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Alon's answer: if you want to observe several properties, then you can use something like this:

```
  properties:{
     someproperty1:{
       type: Number,
     }
     someProperty2:{
       type: Number,
     }
  },

  observers: ['change(someproperty1, someproperty2)'],

  change:function(property1, property2){
    //this function called when the property changes.
  },
```

Note, when using single observers, they will fire in the order they are set. So if `someproperty1` and `someproperty2` had specific observers binded to them, then the method that `someproperty1` had will be executed first.

To read more about observers, read here:
https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/observers#multi-property-observers